# Azure TableStorage HowTo?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-3-areas, azure-table-storage

I want to store Contacts on to Azure table(name and gender as a property). so I basically two classes . the one which derives from the TableSerivceContext and the other from TableServiceEntity. now I cant connect the pieces. What I will really do at the cotroller(I use MVC3)

tnx for any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im assuming that you are receiving the properties (name and gender) via post from a view.
so your controller might be like this

```
public ActionResult DoSomething(User model)
{

}
```

so what you need to do is.. that. make a new ofject of the class thats derived from the TableServiceEntity. and assign the Properties.
like this

```
var tableUser = new TableUser(){Name = model.Name, Gender=model.Gender}
```

then from the class derived from TableServiceContext make an object. and use `AddObject()` method to add the user to the table
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.addobject.aspx

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done recently to create a very simple MVC3 + Windows Azure Table sample application:

1. Created a Model Class DataEntity inherit from TableServiceEntity which include all the table properties needed to store along with PartitionKey and RowKey
2. Created another Model class DataContext inherit from TableServiceConext which includes IQueryable sets up the Table
3. Created a Controller class which creates HTTPGet and HTTPPost method type ViewResult returning View. The controller also have code to create the Table first using Model DataContext type and then added code to call AddObject as DataEntity type as below:

DataContext context = new DataContext(storageAccount.TableEndpoint.AbsoluteUri, storageAccount.Credentials); 
context.AddObject("DataEntryTable", dataEntity); 
context.SaveChanges();

Finally you can create views from the controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to inherit ‘Contact’ from TableServiceEntity and a context class from TableServiceContext to provide all the methods to manage your ‘Contact’ entities. You can then invoke methods on the ‘Context’ class from anywhere (including the controller).

I have written an alternate Azure table storage client, Lucifure Stash, which does away with having to inherit from any base calls and supports additional abstractions over azure table storage. Lucifure Stash supports large data columns > 64K, arrays & lists, enumerations, composite keys, out of the box serialization, user defined morphing, public and private properties and fields and more.
It is available free for personal use at http://www.lucifure.com  or via NuGet.com.

Answer (score 0):

Download the [Windows Azure Platform Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8396) and do the lab on Windows Azure Storage.  In 15 minutes you will have a working prototype.